# Tiny scroll bar auto height

Tags: jquery, css, scrollbar, custom-scrolling

I have used tiny scroll bar inside a pop up. Scrolling div has accordion menu in it.

When the accordion menu is expanded  scroll bar is getting extended but for some reason I am unable to see the last accordion item when scroll down. I believe it is taking some fixed height so that the last items are not seen.

And also whenever the new accordion menu is clicked, scroll bar is again starting from the top of the div but I want this to stay at the menu's place.

Here is the code and demo below

```
$('#test').click(function(){
        $('#dialog').show();
    $('#scrollbar1').tinyscrollbar();   
     $('#overlay').show();
});
//Accordion
    $('#accordion-3').dcAccordion({
        eventType: 'click',
        autoClose: true,
        saveState: false,
        disableLink: false,
        showCount: false,
        speed: 'slow'
    });
$('#accordion-3').click(function(){
    $('#scrollbar1').tinyscrollbar();
    });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GknfT/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

From what i saw in the fiddle, the tinyscrollbar does not update once the height of the accordion is modified on collapse. For this you need to use the update() method of the tinyscrollbar. But the weird thing is, I haven't found a bindable event in the dcaccordion documentation, so that I can inject the update after the animation. I've slightly modified your example to use the accordion from jquery UI and it works fine with that, you can customize that one any way you want. Hope it helps. 
This is my modified code:

```
$('#accordion-3').accordion({
activate: function (event, ui) {
    var oScrollbar = $('#scrollbar1');
    oScrollbar.tinyscrollbar_update('relative');
},
heightStyle: "content",
alwaysOpen: false,
active: false,
collapsible: true
```

});

[modified fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/GknfT/13/)